# Gtkmm-app crashes on windows 8.1 when resizing window

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, gtkmm

I developed an app with gtkmm in visual studio about 1 year ago. No problem when I had Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010. Now when I run it one year later on windows 8.1 and compiled in Visual Studio 2012 - I can launch it BUT as soon as I try to resize the window or press the OK-button it crashes.

I can see in the debugger that it crashes in the callback-functions here when resizing the window:

```
cr = window->create_cairo_context();
```

and here when pressing ok-button:

```
}
```

that is at the end of the callback-function when it returns.

here are the source code (callback-functions)

```
 void MyWindow::on_button_clicked(Glib::ustring data) {

Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> window = myDrawingArea.get_window();

if(window)
{

    Gtk::Allocation allocation = myDrawingArea.get_allocation();
    const int width = allocation.get_width();
    const int height = allocation.get_height();
    std::cout << "w = " << width << std::endl;

    // coordinates for the center of the window
    int xc, yc;
    xc = width / 2;
    yc = height / 2;

    Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cr = window->create_cairo_context();

    cr->set_line_width(1.0);
    std::cout << "hello in on_button_clicked!!!\n";

    a = 0;
    b = 300;
    c = 200;
    d = 150;
    e = 350;
    f = 400;
    // draw red lines out from the center of the window
    cr->set_source_rgb(0.8, 0.5, 0.0);
    cr->move_to(a, b);
    cr->line_to(c, d);
    cr->move_to(c, d);
    cr->line_to(e, f);

    cr->stroke();
    std::cout << "here comes crasch!!!\n";
}
```

and the other (resizing)

```
 bool MyWindow::on_drawing_expose_event(GdkEventExpose* event) {

Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> window = myDrawingArea.get_window();
if(window)
{
    std::cout << "here comes crasch!!!\n";
        cr = window->create_cairo_context();
```

and the debugger gives me this info

```
    sigc::trackable <Unable to read memory> 
    Glib::ObjectBase    <Unable to read memory>
```

and the callstack

```
 >  ConsoleApplication4.exe!MyWindow::on_drawing_expose_event(_GdkEventExpose * event) Line 173 C++
ConsoleApplication4.exe!sigc::internal::slot_call1<sigc::bound_mem_functor1<bool,MyWindow,_GdkEventExpose *>,bool,_GdkEventExpose *>::call_it(sigc::internal::slot_rep * rep, _GdkEventExpose * const & a_1) Line 137   C++
gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll!100a549b()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll]   
libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll!61859f1e()   Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a45aca() Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a567e4() Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a5dafe() Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a5de66() Unknown
libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6197a0f7()   Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c363fe9()   Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c363f9d()   Unknown
msvcrt.dll!_free() Unknown
msvcrt.dll!_free() Unknown
000000a8()  Unknown
msvcrt.dll!_free() Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f6947()    Unknown
gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll!10011723()  Unknown
gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll!10024836()  Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a45aca() Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a56438() Unknown
libgobject-2.0-0.dll!63a5dcd6() Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_WaitForMultipleObjectsEx@20()  Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c34137c()   Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f09eb()    Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f1205()    Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f13f5()    Unknown
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()  Unknown
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()   Unknown
user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcWorker()    Unknown
user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcW() Unknown
uxtheme.dll!DoMsgDefault(struct _THEME_MSG const *) Unknown
uxtheme.dll!OnDwpSysCommand()   Unknown
uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProc()   Unknown
uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProcW@16()  Unknown
user32.dll!DefWindowProcW() Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c37db18()   Unknown
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()  Unknown
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()   Unknown
user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcWorker()    Unknown
user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcW() Unknown
uxtheme.dll!DoMsgDefault(struct _THEME_MSG const *) Unknown
uxtheme.dll!OnDwpNcLButtonDown()    Unknown
uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProc()   Unknown
uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProcW@16()  Unknown
user32.dll!DefWindowProcW() Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c37db18()   Unknown
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()   Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c37dbe4()   Unknown
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll!6c37dc16()   Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f09eb()    Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685f1205()    Unknown
libglib-2.0-0.dll!685efb1c()    Unknown
libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll!61857694()   Unknown
msvcr100.dll!_free()   Unknown
msvcr100.dll!_free()   Unknown
sigc-vc100-2_0.dll!00092516()   Unknown
gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll!10045a4f()  Unknown
ConsoleApplication4.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 10   C++
ConsoleApplication4.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536    C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
```

So I wonder whats wrong - since it used to run without problem on the other platform?

*Greatful for help. If someone wants to see the whole source and try it I can post it.*

Comment: `gtkmm-vc100-2_4.dll` This is a Visual Studio 2010 dll used on Visual Studio 2012 which will cause you to have more than 1 independent heap where you can not allocate memory in your application and free it in the dll or vise versa without corrupting the heaps. My advice is make sure you use dlls compiled for your compiler. Edit: Also remember that Visual Studio 2012 is vc110 not vc120.

Comment: @drescherjm - I think I need a later version of gtkmm? The repository I downloaded from is from 2010. (thats why I have gtkmm-vc100-2_4) I have searched but cannot find any later releases by now. Do you know how to find it?

Comment: I do not know where to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is compiler version, you either need to compile fresh gtkmm from source by using Visual Studio 2013 and then rebuild your application.

Second option is to install older version of Visual Studio and rebuild your app and target XP.

If you decide to compile latest gtkmm (3.14) with Visual Studio 2013 I made a tutorial [link1](https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm) [link2](http://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/) on how to do that. anyway on my GitHub page you can also find prebult gtkmm 3.14 for Visual Studio 2013 debug for Windows x64